# Using subclass of std::unique_ptr with std::variant

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, unique-ptr, variant

I have a subclass of `std::unique_ptr` and am trying to use it with `std::variant`. I have the following setup

```cpp
// main.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

using namespace std;

class Content {
  public:
    Content() = default;
    ~Content() { cout << "deconstructing Content" << endl; };

    int value = 10;
};

template<typename T>
class Wrapper : public unique_ptr<T> {
  public:
    Wrapper(T *value): unique_ptr<T>(value) {};
    ~Wrapper() { cout << "deconstructing Wrapper" << endl; };
};

static variant<Wrapper<Content>, int> do_sth(bool flag) {
  if (flag) return Wrapper(new Content());
  return 1;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  auto result = do_sth(true);
  if (auto wrapper = get_if<Wrapper<Content>>(&result)) {
    cout << wrapper->get()->value << endl;
  } else {
    cout << *get_if<int>(&result) << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

compiled on macOS 10.14 with Xcode 10.1 using

```sh
$ #c++ --version -> Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
$ c++ -std=gnu++17 main.cc
```

The compiler complaints with the following

```
main.cc:25:12: error: no viable conversion from returned value of type 'Wrapper<Content>' to function return type 'variant<Wrapper<Content>, int>'
    return Wrapper(new Content());
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/variant:1142:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: no
      known conversion from 'Wrapper<Content>' to 'const std::__1::variant<Wrapper<Content>, int> &' for 1st argument
  variant(const variant&) = default;
  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/variant:1155:13: note: candidate template ignored:
      substitution failure [with _Arg = Wrapper<Content>, $1 = 0, $2 = 0, $3 = 0]: no type named 'type' in
      'std::__1::result_of<std::__1::__variant_detail::__overload<Wrapper<Content>, int> (Wrapper<Content> &&)>'
  constexpr variant(_Arg&& __arg) noexcept(
            ^
1 error generated.
```

I have two questions: First, what am I doing wrong? Second, when I remove the deconstructor of `Wrapper`, i.e.,

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Wrapper : public unique_ptr<T> {
  public:
    Wrapper(T *value): unique_ptr<T>(value) {};
};
```

then it compiles and runs with the following output

```
10
deconstructing Content
```

Why does it (seem to?) work without deconstructor?

Comment: "what am I doing wrong?" subclassing `unique_ptr` is a major red flag. Unrelatedly `get_if` misses the point of `std::variant`

Comment: @Caleth As you can see I am very new to C++. Can you explain or point me to a link why subclassing `unique_ptr` is not a good practice? Thanks.

Comment: inheritance is blunt instrument. Other options are often much more appropriate. If a class has no protected members, it probably shouldn't be subclassed. In this case you can change the `Deleter` parameter of `std::unique_ptr` to one that prints the message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Wrapper` inherits from `unique_ptr` instance of this class can be only moved.

You have defined destructor for Wrapper so move operations (constructor and assignment operator) are *deleted* - you can read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) when move operations are generated by compiler.

You could:

1) remove destructor of Wrapper, then compiler generates default move operations

or

2) add move operations

```
Wrapper(T *value): unique_ptr<T>(value) {};
Wrapper(Wrapper&&) = default; // added
~Wrapper() { cout << "deconstructing Wrapper" << endl; };
```

Comment: is it because it's "user-provided"?  or just "defined"?  I was surprised that =default'ing the destructor still doesn't compile

Comment: @xaxxon Default move operations are disabled when destructor is *user-declared*, *user-declared* is when `default/delete` appears at member/destructor, user-provided is when definition of method was added.